# How can I position these elements correctly?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

To practice with tailwind I'm trying to make a app based on this site: https://aniketkotal.me At this point I'm having trouble with positioning some elements. Could someone help me out here?

[what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0glIE.png)

I would like the text in the red circle to be in the middle of the page like is done in the site I try to replicate. This is what I have so far:

```
<div>
 <div class="pb-8">
  <div>
    <h1 class="text-xl sm:text-3xl text-white md:text-4xl pb-6">
      Student software development.
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p class="text-sm text-white md:text-base leading-relaxed slg:text-lg slg:leading-8">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu eros vulputate, lobortis nulla a, lobortis libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Etiam felis nunc, eleifend non dictum non, feugiat in risus. Pellentesque malesuada lacus eros, nec dapibus eros ornare ut. Vestibulum in efficitur mauris. Sed at vulputate augue, vel egestas ex. Nunc vel leo quis lacus bibendum laoreet. Phasellus iaculis, libero a vestibulum imperdiet, ex ipsum placerat nibh, in tempus felis ipsum quis felis. In porttitor mauris in nisl elementum, et porttitor sapien tempus. Morbi sit amet magna sed urna semper sollicitudin. Aliquam interdum quam ac nunc sollicitudin, quis ornare nisi faucibus. Etiam est mauris, tristique sed ipsum sed, pellentesque consectetur quam. Nunc vel mollis nisi.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex pt-4">
      <div class="flex gap-4 h-20 w-20">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" title="GitHub"><img src="../../../data/icons/github.png"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" title="LinkedIn"><img src="../../../data/icons/linkedin.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The list in the blue circle I would like to be in the middle of the grey block. This is what I have right now:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 pt-8 w-3/5 gap-6">
  <div class="flex p-6 gap-8 rounded-md bg-zinc-700 mb-8 text-white">
    <!-- Frontend -->
    <div>
      <h3 class="font-theme_bold text-base md:text-xl lg:text-2xl text-head_text">
        Frontend
      </h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="flex p-2" v-for="frontend in skill.frontend" :key="frontend.id">
          - {{frontend.name}}
          <img class="ml-2 max-h-6 max-w-6" :src="frontend.icon" alt="icon">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Backend -->
    <div>
      <h3 class="font-theme_bold text-base md:text-xl lg:text-2xl text-head_text">
        Backend
      </h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="flex p-2" v-for="backend in skill.backend" :key="backend.id">
          - {{backend.name}}
          <img class="ml-2 max-h-6 max-w-6" :src="backend.icon" alt="icon">
          <br>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The text in the green circle I want to put at the start of the divs its between (yellow line). Here is the div with the classes I have right now:

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center pb-8 bg-zinc-800">
 <div class="items-start">
  <div class="flex flex-col pt-4 text-white">
    <h3 class="font-theme_bold text-base md:text-xl lg:text-2xl text-head_text">My projects</h3>
    <p>Here are some of the projects I have worked on</p>
  </div>
 </div
</div>
```

I have searched for answers in the tailwind documentation but I find this hard to understand.
The end result I would want to look something like this:
[result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aqny.png)
[result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94QzA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the text, consider applying

```css
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 48rem; /* Or another value of your choosing */
padding-left: 2.5rem; /* Or another value of your choosing */
padding-right: 2.5rem; /* Or another value of your choosing */
```

to a containing element via the Tailwind classes `mx-auto max-w-3xl px-10`. We add `max-w-*` class to limit the width of the text to a maximum amount. This is so that the `mx-auto` can then center it horizontally. We add some horizontal padding with `px-*` so that when the viewport is smaller than the `max-w-*`, there is some spacing between the edges of the viewport and the text.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="px-10 max-w-3xl mx-auto">
 <div class="pb-8">
  <div>
    <h1 class="text-xl sm:text-3xl text-white md:text-4xl pb-6">
      Student software development.
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p class="text-sm text-white md:text-base leading-relaxed slg:text-lg slg:leading-8">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu eros vulputate, lobortis nulla a, lobortis libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Etiam felis nunc, eleifend non dictum non, feugiat in risus. Pellentesque malesuada lacus eros, nec dapibus eros ornare ut. Vestibulum in efficitur mauris. Sed at vulputate augue, vel egestas ex. Nunc vel leo quis lacus bibendum laoreet. Phasellus iaculis, libero a vestibulum imperdiet, ex ipsum placerat nibh, in tempus felis ipsum quis felis. In porttitor mauris in nisl elementum, et porttitor sapien tempus. Morbi sit amet magna sed urna semper sollicitudin. Aliquam interdum quam ac nunc sollicitudin, quis ornare nisi faucibus. Etiam est mauris, tristique sed ipsum sed, pellentesque consectetur quam. Nunc vel mollis nisi.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex pt-4">
      <div class="flex gap-4 h-20 w-20">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" title="GitHub"><img src="../../../data/icons/github.png"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" title="LinkedIn"><img src="../../../data/icons/linkedin.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

For the icons use a [flex layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to align the  elements horizontally centered, inside the gray box.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="max-w-3xl mx-auto p-10 rounded-md bg-zinc-700 text-white">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-6 justify-center">
    <!-- Frontend -->
    <div>
      <h3 class="font-theme_bold text-base md:text-xl lg:text-2xl text-head_text">
        Frontend
      </h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="flex p-2">
          - {{frontend.name}}
          <img class="ml-2 max-h-6 max-w-6" src="https://picsum.photos/28/28" alt="icon"/>
        </li>
        <li class="flex p-2">
          - {{frontend.name}}
          <img class="ml-2 max-h-6 max-w-6" src="https://picsum.photos/28/28?0" alt="icon"/>
        </li>
        <li class="flex p-2">
          - {{frontend.name}}
          <img class="ml-2 max-h-6 max-w-6" src="https://picsum.photos/28/28?1" alt="icon"/>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Backend -->
    <div>
      <h3 class="font-theme_bold text-base md:text-xl lg:text-2xl text-head_text">
        Backend
      </h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="flex p-2">
          - {{backend.name}}
          <img class="ml-2 max-h-6 max-w-6" src="https://picsum.photos/28/28?2" alt="icon">
          <br>
        </li>
        <li class="flex p-2">
          - {{backend.name}}
          <img class="ml-2 max-h-6 max-w-6" src="https://picsum.photos/28/28?3" alt="icon">
          <br>
        </li>
        <li class="flex p-2">
          - {{backend.name}}
          <img class="ml-2 max-h-6 max-w-6" src="https://picsum.photos/28/28?4" alt="icon">
          <br>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the the text in the green circle, it seems like you have not provided enough valid code make a reproducible example and as such, I am unable to provide any remedy for that.

### Edit

For the the text in the green circle, consider applying `align-self: flex-start` to the container of the text via the `self-start` class:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex flex-col items-center pb-8 bg-zinc-800">
  <div class="items-start self-start">
    <div class="flex flex-col pt-4 text-white">
      <h3 class="font-theme_bold text-base md:text-xl lg:text-2xl text-head_text">My projects</h3>
      <p>Here are some of the projects I have worked on</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for helping me out! May I ask what more code you need for the green circle?

Comment: I don't know, because I can't see the code that I need to see!

Comment: the code is provided in my question

Comment: Yes, as I said in my original answer, it seems like you have not provided enough valid code make a reproducible example and as such, I am unable to provide any remedy for that.

Comment: I think I fixed it, I forgot to put one div in the example. It is there now

Comment: Thanks alot for helping me out and explaining